# How to hide labels of unchecked checkboxes?

Tags: jquery

I need to hide checkboxes and their labels when the checkboxes are not checked.

```js
// this works for checkboxes:
//$("input:checkbox").not(":checked").hide();

// ERROR: this hides all labels
$("input:checkbox").not(":checked").parent().find('label').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff95614668d">Sport</label> 

<input class="" id="checkbox57ff95614668d" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="1" checked="">
    
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff9561466d3">cinéma</label> 
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff9561466d3" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="2" checked="">
    
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff956146712">lecture</label> 
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff956146712" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="3">
```

Comment: What is your DOM structure?

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(":checked").hide().prev('label').hide()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) that select previus sibling of element. Also you can use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selecot instead `.not()` method.

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").prev().hide();
```

```js
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").hide().prev().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff95614668d">Sport</label>
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff95614668d" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="1" checked="">
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff9561466d3">cinéma</label>
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff9561466d3" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="2" checked="">
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff956146712">lecture</label>
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff956146712" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="3">
```

If `label` isn't previous sibling of `input`, you can select target label using [Attribute Equals Selector `[name=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). As you know `id` of input is equal to `for` attribute of label.

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function(){
    $(this).hide().siblings("label[for='"+ this.id +"']").hide();
});
```

```js
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function(){ 
    $(this).hide().siblings("label[for='"+ this.id +"']").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff95614668d">Sport</label>
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff95614668d" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="1" checked="">
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff9561466d3">cinéma</label>
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff9561466d3" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="2" checked="">
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff956146712">lecture</label>
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff956146712" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="3">
```

Comment: While `prev` is simplest and fastest, it's not the best approach. It relies on the structure of the DOM not changing and the relation implied by the order of DOM elements. If that order changes, this code will begin to fail silently, potentially hiding the wrong element. The better solution is the one that leverages the real existing semantic relationship between the label and its input defined by the `for` attribute of the label. The solutions looking up labels using `$("label[for=" + ... + "])"` are the better solutions for maintainability and just plain correctness.

Comment: @meagar Good mention.

Answer (score 2):

> **prev() :** Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.

You could use **[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** to select the previous `label` by passing `"label"` as parameter :

```js
$('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').hide().prev('label').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff95614668d">Sport</label> <input class="" id="checkbox57ff95614668d" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="1" checked="">
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff9561466d3">cinéma</label> <input class="" id="checkbox57ff9561466d3" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="2" checked="">
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff956146712">lecture</label> <input class="" id="checkbox57ff956146712" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="3">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function.

With this function, it doesn't matter where the label is positioned. Only thing important is to use the `id` attribute on your checkbox and `for` attribute on your label.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('label[for='+$(this).attr('id')+']').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff95614668d">Sport</label>
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff95614668d" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="1" checked="">
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff9561466d3">cinéma</label>
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff9561466d3" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="2" checked="">
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkbox57ff956146712">lecture</label>
<input class="" id="checkbox57ff956146712" type="checkbox" name="userhobby[]" value="3">
```

Comment: Sadly this is now the best answer, but it accumulated a few downvotes before it was edited to be correct.

Comment: @meagar Well, the downvotes on my first answer were correct... the code didn't work. The downvoters won't see the edit (unless they revisit the question). I understand it. No problem for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the id of the checkbox to aid in the filtering:

```
$('input:checkbox').not(':checked').each(function(i, el){ 
    $(el).parent().find('label[for="' + el.id + '"]').hide(); 
});
```

Or, if you want something more robust and structure-independant:

```
$('input:checkbox').not(':checked').each(function(i, el){ 
    $('label[for="' + el.id + '"]').hide(); 
});
```

Comment: Far better than using `prev`, but it still relies on the structure of the DOM not changing over time. The first time a designer comes in and adds a `<div>` around the checkbox so they can achieve some kind of front-end styling, this code will break.